# Disabling right-click on images doesn't work on ipad and iphones

Tags: jquery, ios, compatibility, web-testing, code-testing

I use the following code to disable right click on images in my website:

```
//disable right click on images
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        if(e.target.nodeName == 'IMG'){
            //context menu attempt on top of an image element
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This works perfectly on desktop and all androids. However, it does not work on Ipads and Iphones. How can I overcome this issue? Please Help.

My website: http://www.feather.com.lk/p-cotton.php

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried CSS: `img{ user-select: none; pointer-events: none; }` ?

Comment: in addition/alternatively you can obscure the images with transparent divs to make the image unreachable by touch options, for the smaller images you can do the same and register the click events from the transparent divs instead of the images.

Comment: @Sam0 when i used the css you mentioned above, it solved my ios issue. Unfortunately i was also unable to click on the tiny thumbnails (see: http://www.feather.com.lk/p-cotton.php) to switch images on the bigger box :(
if you don't mind can you please show an example of your second comment?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to allow 'pointer-events' on your thumbnail images by adding it to a 'thumbnail' class `.thumbnail { pointer-events: auto; }`. This would allow a user to rightclick download a small thumbnail on iOS.

Another option is to wrap each thumbnail with an adjacent 'thumbwrapper' div to receive click events. In this case a user would be pulling up a context menu on a div instead of an image.

You should also consider using `.on` instead of `.bind` as the latter as been deprecated in many newer versions of jquery.

```js
//disable right click on images
$('img').on("contextmenu", function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'img') {
    //context menu attempt on top of an image element
    return false;
  }
});

$('.mask').on('click', function() {
  $('body').append('clicked <br>');

  // using a div above as well as or instead of the 'pointer-events' css to intercept user clicks
});
```

```css
.thumbwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 25%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  top: 2%;
  height: 30%;
  border: 2px solid #09f;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='thumbwrapper'>
  <img src='https://68.media.tumblr.com/2211e6baf28cb6ae2d4ec644cf8227ef/tumblr_okb3a8PM0E1tg322jo1_540.jpg' />
</div>

<div class='thumbwrapper'>
  <div class='mask'>
  </div>
  <img src='https://68.media.tumblr.com/2211e6baf28cb6ae2d4ec644cf8227ef/tumblr_okb3a8PM0E1tg322jo1_540.jpg' />
</div>

<div class='thumbwrapper'>
  <img src='https://68.media.tumblr.com/2211e6baf28cb6ae2d4ec644cf8227ef/tumblr_okb3a8PM0E1tg322jo1_540.jpg' />
</div>
```